# ngFor is only setting value of last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have an array of objects called `this.itemsArray`. The object inside the array contains the attribute `rate`. The `rate` is set using `[(ngModel)]` when the user enters a value.

Whenever the user enters the `rate`, I want to show the button below. If the user does NOT enter the `rate`, then I want to hide the button.

The code works fine if there is only 1 item (and hence one rate) in the array. The issue comes when there are more than one items (and hence more than one rate in the array). In this case, the problem is that the button is being hidden ONLY when the LAST item (rate) in the array has a value.

I need the button to be hidden whenever ANY of the rates in the array are blank. How can I achieve this?

```
 <div *ngFor = "let item of this.itemsArray;  let i = index">
                                                                            
     <button  *ngIf = "this.itemsArray[i].rate" >Proceed</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `let i = index`, use `index as i`. https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: Also, the usage of index is not needed; you can just refer to `item`

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: I changed around ```let i = index``` to ```index as i```. I also changed ```this.itemsArray[i].rate``` to ```item.rate``` but still having the same issue. I am using ```Angular: 10.1.0```

Comment: This wasn't the issue, just side notes

Comment: The expected behavior is a bit unclear. Let's say you have two items in the array and only one of them has the rate set. Do you want to show the button for that item and not for the other?

Comment: Hi Henrik, there is only one ```Proceed``` button. If I have two items in the array and only one of them has the rate set, then I do not want to show the Proceed button. To be clear, the ```Proceed``` button should ONLY be shown when all the items in the array has a rate set.

Answer (score 1):

You already are using a single element `item`. Why to use `this.itemsArray[i].rate`??

```
 <div *ngFor = "let item of this.itemsArray;  let i = index">
                                                                            
   <button  *ngIf = "item && item.rate" >Proceed</button> // Replace this.itemsArray[i] with item

</div>

// the condition item && item.rate ==> it will check if the item is there and item.rate is there. If its not there, it wont display that element in the DOM
```

Answer (score 0):

you should process the items at some point in the ts file (smth like `this.hideButton = this.itemsArray.some(item => !item.rate)`) and then in the template `<button  *ngIf = "!hideButton" >Proceed</button>`

Comment: I'll try this shortly and get back to you. Thanks!